# Axios GET request component not being rended on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, meteor, axios

I am having trouble in rendering my components onto screen, after the promise is done. I am using imgur api to send requests, everything is working fine with request, I am receiving back data back from API. However, when I update the state from my component and pass in props, no data is received.

Here is my parent component `app.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ImageList from './image_list';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {images: []};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // IMGUR_URL returns an array of 60 objects.
        axios.get(IMGUR_URL).then(res => this.setState({images: res.data.data}));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                // Passing in the images state
                <ImageList images={this.state.images} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I saw some examples using `componentDidMount` function. However, I did not see any changes into my app.

Here are my two child components:
The `props` value are getting from ImageList component.

`image_detail.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class ImageDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    <img src={this.props.image.images[0].link} alt={this.props.image.title} />
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`props` value are coming from App.js from axios GET request. So I am not sure what am I missing out here.

`image_list.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ImageDetail from './image_detail';

export default class ImageList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.RenderedImages = this.props.images.map(image => <ImageDetail key={image.id} image={image} />);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul> {this.RenderedImages} </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And also another question, what should I put inside the `constructor` method?

Comment: what does `res.data.data` returns an `{ }` or an `[ ]`

Comment: Returns an 60x `[ {}, {}, {}...]`

Comment: Have you tried replacing `[ ]` with `{ }` like this `this.state = {images: { } };` inside your `app.js`

Comment: I already solved my problem. And `this.state` must return as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And also another question, what should I put inside the constructor method?

Generally, state initialization should go in the constructor

For `ImageList` component, I'd suggest you move `RenderedImages` into the `render` function, Like so:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ImageDetail from './image_detail';

export default class ImageList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul> {this.props.images.map(image => <ImageDetail key={image.id} image={image} />)} </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that works, but I am still wondering why should it is working all the sudden?

Comment: because ```render()``` method gets called by React when state is updated or new props are passed from parent component